# The T-1000 doesn't have flesh, so how can it time-travel?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In Terminator: Genisys, it's explained that any exposed metal can't travel through time. Only metal that's covered in living tissue (like a terminator) or a fully-naked human. So how can a T-1000 time travel, since it's 100% (liquid) metal?

Comment: And the corrupted John Conner himself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94900/20774) to the same question on Scifi:SE

According to the film's Visual Effects editor, this was left [somewhat ambiguous](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2FAQ.htm):

> **Van Ling:** *That idea (flesh cocoon) was one we had bandied about during preproduction, but it was something that we thought would be
>   too confusing to show visually it would have been like when Brett
>   finds the shed alien skin in Alien. I still think it's the most
>   logical explanation, given we see a flesh "mold" in the teaser trailer
>   already. The other possibilities are that 1) the T-1000 could mimic
>   the field generated by a living organism or 2) Reese really does NOT
>   know tech stuff. Note that several comics and other media later played
>   off the idea of surgically embedding weapons into human carriers and
>   ripping them out of them once they arrived*
>
> *Originally there was suppose to be a scene showing officer Joe Austin finding the skin. it was something that we thought would be too
>   confusing to show visually it would have been like when Brett finds
>   the shed alien skin in Alien*

That said, the film's [official novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)) makes it extremely clear what has happened.

> They walked underneath them to the place where the [two 20-ton plates](https://youtu.be/us3ggae8-Ec?t=52s)
>   met and peered within the small gap there. it was only large enough
>   for a single man to step between and there was an indention in each of
>   the plates, an indention in the shape of a man. Connor squinted at
>   something gleaming at the edge of a small round opening positioned
>   where the neck of a man would be in the lower indention. He squatted,
>   feeling his age in his aching knees, and shined his light at what had
>   caught his eye. He carefully extended the tip of his plasma rifle down
>   into the indention, using the barrel of the well used weapon to prod
>   what appeared to be a large drop of liquid mercury. As the barrel of
>   his rifle touched the liquid it flowed onto the barrel of his rifle
>   and seemed to soak in, disappearing.